# Navigationbar is positioned below the hidden statusbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, hidden, uistatusbar

coming from a TableView, I am creating an MKMapView. I want to have more screen real estate, so I hide the status bar und set the navigation bar to transluscent.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Unfortunaltely the navigation bar is positioned below the hidden status bar (see picture).

[image]

I already found out that this might help, since one can perform kind of a reload of the bar in the main event loop:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setNavigationController:YES) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

But this doesn't work so far. Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code you posted actually sets the status bar to visible and the navbar to not transluscent?

Comment: Uppps, I corrected the piece of code. Thanks Peter

Comment: You know you have a typo in your code? `setNavigationConroller` instead of `setNavigationController`. I'm assuming that's what you wanted at least. (I can't confirm or deny if that would do what you want though)

Comment: Thanks for the typo report - I fixed it in the above code (I had fixed it earlier in project before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found out what to do:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setNavigationController:NO) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
[self performSelector:@selector(setNavigationController:YES) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

This switches the navigation bar off and on again, which forces it to redraw in the correct position.

Comment: `setNavigationController:` is probably a private API, did you manage to get this approved by Apple?

Comment: no, in the end I took it out because there where more workarounds required to get this to work perfectly in my app - which was not possible within the given time.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in iOS 6:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```